# How to avoid recursion calling scrollIntoView() in scroll event-handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, scroll

I want to divide my site into several screen-sized section and automatically scroll to the next section when user starts scrolling. To achieve it I wrote code like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    getElementToScroll().scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
}
```

But there's a recursion caused by calling `scrollIntoView()`. How can I avoid this problem? Maybe there's another more suitable way to scroll element into view?

P.S. Smooth behavior is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS Scroll Snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap) to achieve this behavior. It requires no JavaScript, just CSS. As of this writing most browsers, except IE and Edge, have [full support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints) of this API.

Check the example below to see it in action.

```css
html,
body,
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always
}

section:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: orange;
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: green;
}

section:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: blue;
}

section:nth-of-type(6) {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <section>First section</section>
  <section>Second section</section>
  <section>Third section</section>
  <section>Fourth section</section>
  <section>Fifth section</section>
  <section>Sixth section</section>
</article>
```